# How to pass shell variable to awk command inside shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I just want to pass a shell variable that stores  name of a file to awk command. When I searched this problem on the net I see many different options but none of them worked for me. I tried the followings:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in "$@"
do
case $i in
    -p=*|--producedfile=*)
    PFILE="${i#*=}"
    shift # past argument=value
    *)
          # unknown option
    ;;
esac
done
echo "PRODUCEDFILE  = ${PFILE}"
awk  -v FILE=${PFILE} '{print FILE $0}' #DIDNT WORK
awk   '{print FILE $0}' ${PFILE} # DIDNT WORK
awk  -v FILE=${PFILE} '{print $0}' FILE #DIDNT WORK
```

Comment: Not sure I get it, `$PFILE` is the name of the file `Awk` should process on (or) just be passed to the body?

Comment: @Inian $PFILE is the name of file Awk should process as you said. 
Let's say this is inside the bash script named mybash.sh. Then I call the following command: bash mybash.sh -p=inputfile.txt

Comment: So why didn't `awk '{print FILE $0}' ${PFILE}` work? Remember `FILE` variable is undefined here. I am sure this would have printed the contents of `inputfile.txt` one line at a time

Comment: If you're calling it with an argument `-p=inputfile.txt`, then there's no need for the shift.  You would `shift` if you called it with `-p inputfile.txt`, in which case the `${i#*=}` doesn't work.  Drop the `shift`.

Answer (score 2):

To pass a shell variable to `awk`, you correctly used `-v` option.

However, the `shift` was unnecessary (you're iterating options with `for`), `;;` was missing (you have to terminate each case branch), as well as was the name of the file for `awk` to process. Fixed, your script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in "$@"; do
    case $i in
        -p=*|--producedfile=*)
            PFILE="${i#*=}"
            ;;
        *)
             # unknown option
            ;;
    esac
done

echo "PRODUCEDFILE = ${PFILE}"
awk  -v FILE="${PFILE}" '{print FILE, $0}' "${PFILE}"
```

Note however, `awk` already makes the name of the currently processed file available in the `FILENAME` variable. So, you could also write the last line as:

```
awk '{print FILENAME, $0}' "${PFILE}"
```